# Did the show Seinfeld come about in a manner similar to the way it was depicted in the show?

Tags: seinfeld

On Seinfeld, Jerry and his friend George proposed a show to NBC executives about 'nothing,' featuring his friends and people he knows.

*How close was the experience of Jerry and George getting 'Jerry' on the air to that of Jerry Seinfeld getting the actual show 'Seinfeld' produced?*

Comment: Wow, interesting question.

Comment: The DVD set has an hour long documentary about how the show began. I'd have to watch it again to remember details, but it was initially supposed to be a 90-min TV special that follows Jerry Seinfeld around and shows how he comes up with his material

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> NBC asked if I had any ideas for a show, and I said no. They sent me away to think about it. Then, a month or two later, I bumped into Larry David (co-creator/executive producer/writer) at one of the clubs in New York and I was telling him about the meeting. We were walking around near one of those little Korean fruit stands that they have in New York, buying some late night groceries, and we were making fun of some of the products there. Larry said, "You know, this is what the show should be: just two comedians making fun of stuff, walking around talking. That was the premise we started with.

according to [Seinfeld](http://www.seinfeld-fan.net/aboutseinfeld.php).